# google BigQuery giving random results when joining within WITH clause

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, with-statement

I d like to get some explanation to the folowing issue:
I am creating a table usith with clause. I have created a pre_final table where i have lets say top 3 orders from the customer. Imagine three columns and rows for one example customer

[image: example of 1 customer].

Now I need to agreagate this table to have only one row per customer, and all his top 3 product. Imagine the result table

[image: desired outcome].

I am trying to achieve this by joining the first table 2 times on each other with condition email = email and always stating rating = 1 for the first table, rating = 2 for the second join and rating = 3 for the third join.

```
    from table a
    left join table b on a.email = b.email AND b.rating= 2 
    left join prepExport2 c on a.email = c.email AND c.pom_cnt = 3
where a.rating = 1
```

I strongly believe that this HAS TO work, however, in BigQuery i am getting always RANDOM results. such as that the final table looks like this:

[image: actual outcome].

That is simply not possible. I know for sure that thisworks for example in Oracle databases. Can I please get some understanding what is going on? Just to note one more time all of this is within WITH CLAUSE. There are no duplicities in email when specifying given rating. Echal rating/email combination is there exactly once. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You don't need to join. Aggregate into an ordered Array, then you can pick offset 0, 1, 2 for your products. It's much simpler and no join needed.

Comment: it is easy to propose another more effective and more reliable solution. But if instead you want explanation on why your current code does not work as expected  - you really should present all relevant parts of the code  - not just tiny portion of it! So you need to clarify what you expect us to help you with and if it is JUST explanation - provide more code!

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select email,
       max(case when rating = 1 then product end) as product_1,
       max(case when rating = 2 then product end) as product_2,
       max(case when rating = 3 then product end) as product_3
from <whatever>
group by email;
```

I can explain why what you are seeing *might* be happening, especially because you have not shown the data that causes the problem nor the code that generates the intermediate result.

Many databases do not store the results of a CTE.  Instead, they recalculate the CTE each time it is referenced.  You might have a construct like this:

```
row_number() over (partition by email order by <something>) as rating
```

The `<something>` might have ties for a given `email`.  And, there is no guarantee what the ordering is in the result set.  So, running the same code twice can (and does) produce different results.

The above solution fixes the problem because the CTE is evaluated only once.  However, you might have a problem with instability in your code and you might want to fix the code that generates the intermediate table, by adding an addition `order by` key so there are no ties.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation and the provided solution. You are 100% right about the partion by. Sorry for not providing more code, but it has couple hundereds of rows + I couldnt really share it due to sensitive information even within the code. Thanks so much again!